# g++ not compiling my c++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I'm fairly new to c++ and compiling, however I have done this in the past and didn't get this problem before. I had someone program something for me and left instructions on how to compile it should I need to make any changes. I first "cd" to the folder that contains all the files, then I run the command he gave me:

```
g++ -o filename main.cpp another.cpp aanother.cpp -L/usr/lib `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lid3 -lcurl -lpthread
```

I do get a few errors, but if I remember correctly those same errors have always been there and never impacted the compilation. For some reason, "filename" is not showing in that folder at all. Am I mistaken in that the new program should be found in the same folder I "cd"ed into? What could be the problem? Why is "filename" not being created?

I don't know if this will help anyone, but here are the errors which I'm pretty sure didn't cause problems in the past:

```
[root@host.domain.net] folder >> g++ -o filename main.cpp another.cpp aanother.cpp -L/usr/lib `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lid3 -lcurl -lpthread
main.cpp:13:21: error: id3/tag.h: No such file or directory
main.cpp:14:30: error: id3/misc_support.h: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function âvoid readConfig()â:
main.cpp:679: error: variable âstd::ifstream myfileâ has initializer but incomplete type
main.cpp:682: error: âwsâ was not declared in this scope
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Here are the errors:
>
> ```
> g++ -o filename main.cpp another.cpp aanother.cpp -L/usr/lib `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lid3 -lcurl -lpthread
> main.cpp:13:21: error: id3/tag.h: No such file or directory
> main.cpp:14:30: error: id3/misc_support.h: No such file or directory
> ```

Q: You need to install an ID3 development package (which includes all needed headers).

On my Centos system, I can check for an ID3 package like this:

```
rpm -qa|grep -i id3
```

One should be able to install it with a command like this:

```
yum install id3v2 id3lib-devel
```

If you have an Ubuntu/Debian system, you can use "apt-get install", or your favorite package manager GUI, instead.

**EDIT**

I just tried the following on Centos 5.5:

```
sudo yum install id3lib id3lib-devel
```

It didn't work:

```
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
c5-testing                                               |  951 B     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package id3lib available.
No package id3lib-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

So I guess the RPM is no longer supported (at least for Centos): you need to download the package directly:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3lib/
- http://www.id3lib.org/

Comment: I have Centos as well but I'm getting a "grpe: command not found". Any other ideas?

Comment: Just realized you meant grep. I do have one called "id3lib-3.8.3-7.el5.rf". I ran "yum id3v2 -libid3-devel" and that just listed the yum options. Running "yum install id3v2" says no id3v2 package available.

Comment: @user371699: You are missing `install` in the install command.

Comment: @honk Yes sir, I ran that exact line as mentioned with install, and it's giving me this: Command line error: no such option: -l. Something to do with the "-libid3-devel" part.

Answer (score 1):

> I do get a few errors, but if I remember correctly those same errors have always been there and never impacted the compilation.

You're mistaken. Errors mean that the compile doesn't finish and no output file is generated. Fix the errors (by installing the id3 headers).

Comment: Do you know if there's any other possible solution, or is that the only problem you see? I'm really baffled as I'm sure I saw the same errors last time when it did work. I just tried removing those two includes and that still didn't help. I'm not sure where to proceed from here...

Comment: No, if it says "error", that means "error". You can still compile if you get warnings, though if you do you should only ignore them if you know where these warnings come from and you are sure that it's safe to ignore them.

Comment: @user371699, the only thing that matters at any one time is the first error. Fix that and recompile - repeat this until it compiles without error. You said "I just tried removing those two includes and that still didn't help". You need to give us more information. Did you still get the `main.cpp:13:21: error: id3/tag.h: No such file or directory` error even after removing that include? If so, you've got a bigger problem - it appears that you are not editing the same file that you are compiling.

Comment: @Aaron I did not get the error related to those two includes, so I did edit the correct file. I meant to say that the compilation still didn't work, as the remaining errors were still there. I'm not sure if they're the cause though. Not sure what else to try here.

Comment: @user371699 of course you still get the remaining errors; that's why you address the *first* error first. The solution is the same as it's been the entire time: install the headers that your code needs to compile.